# datatable to Excel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, c#-4.0

While exporting Datatable to Excel some columns to fall into a new line. I don't know what the problem is. My code is below:

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Test.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
string tab = "";
foreach (DataColumn dc in transposedTable.Columns)
{
    Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
    //tab = "\t";
}
Response.Write("\t");
int i;
foreach (DataRow dr in transposedTable.Rows)
{
    Response.Write("\n");
    tab = "";
    for (i = 0; i < transposedTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
        tab = "\t";
    }
    Response.Write("\t");
}
Response.End();
```

I have tried many ways, but didn't get the exact issue. Is the issue with excel in machine or with my code?

Comment: How many columns are in your datatable? Sounds like there are too many.

Comment: I have 35 columns in datatable... After 18 th column its goes to new line.

Comment: Please move the first line of your text from the code wrapper (unindent it). Also, do you mean "but got the exact issue" or "but didn't get the exact issue" is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible that your DataRow data contains newline characters, that is one reason why newlines might be appearing in your data.

Swapping:

```
    Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
```

For:

```
    string replacement = Regex.Replace(dr[i].ToString(), @"\t|\n|\r", "");
    Response.Write(tab + replacement);
```

May fix the problem if I did diagnose it correctly.